# Drop Down lists changing user selection automatically (Visual Basic in Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

A drop down list is changing my selection back to one option no matter what is selected. The drop down list uses imported values from an Sql server, and this is working in two other drop downs. I honestly have no  idea why this is caused, and I have AutoPostBack on, as the other two drop downs work perfectly.

I was going to include some code, but this is for a class and I don't want to get flagged later for plagiarism. If you have follow up questions I would be happy to answer.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: If you're handling the dropdowns SelectedIndexChanged event, make sure that you're not manually setting it back to a predefined index. Also, check that your DataSource is not getting set multiple times.